# Change link HREF attribute when input value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to manipulate the HTML code (a link target), depending on the value of a form input. As soon as the value of the input is changed by the user, I want the value of the link target to be updated.

```
<a href="/#SINGULAR/.htm">foo</a>
<input type="text" name="singular" id="singular">
<script>
$('#singular').on('input', function() {
  //Change the link HREF.
});
</script>
```

Comment: When do you want to do it?

Comment: instantly - when I type the word in the input field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have the binding, so now you just need to target the link and change it.  I suggest putting a class or id on it.

```
$(selector).prop('href', newValue);
```

if you want to just take whatever they type in the input as the new value it would just be

```
$(selector).prop('href', this.value);
```

```js
$('#singular').on('input', function() {
  $('#myLink').prop('href', this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/#SINGULAR/.htm" id="myLink">foo</a>
<input type="text" name="singular" id="singular">
```

Comment: `$(selector).prop('href', this.value);`Works fine for me, tx

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event if you want to do some actions when something is typed in the textbox. To get the value of this textbox, you can use `val()` method of `this` reference (which will point to needed textbox).

```
$('#singular').on('keyup', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Or:

```
$('#singular').keyup(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```